# Preload fields_form fields with data from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, fields-for

I have a form to build several objects following Ryan Bates’ nested form tutorials ([#196](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and [#197](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)). My form looks like this:

```
<%=form_for @group_poll, :remote => true do |f|%>
   <%=f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
      <%=render "group_polls/question_fields",  :f => builder%>    
   <%end%>
   <p><%= link_to_add_group_question "#{t(:addquestion)}", f, :questions%></p>
<%end%>
```

The partial looks like:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3"><%=f.label "#{t(:question)}:"%></div>
    <div class="span3"><%=f.text_field :admin_question, :required => true%></div>
    <div class="span1"><%=f.submit "#{t(:send)}", :name => "send_#{f.object.id}", :class=>"btn-white"%></div>
    <div class="span1"><%=f.submit "#{t(:save)}", :name => "save_#{f.object.id}", :class=>"btn-white"%></div>
</div>
```

I want to preload some questions that exist in the DB when accessing the page in the app and also have the chance to add new questions. In the controller action I have
`@group_poll.questions.build()`
for each poll. It works OK for generating the questions' fields, but they are empty. I don’t know how to preload those polls with the data in DB. I tried passing the `question` object `@group_poll.questions.build(question)`, but I had no luck. I followed this [SO question’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999570/preloading-form-data), but I get lost.

Is it posible what I want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to preload existing questions in the DB, you shouldn't use `build()` because it builds and empty object.

If you take `build()` out, does it work?

```
@group_poll.questions
```

Comment: I was not able to make it work like you said, but your answer lighted me up and I found a solution :)